# Bypass OpenID. Please give us a simple login form

Tags: feature-request, openid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does StackOverflow use OpenID?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46065/why-does-stackoverflow-use-openid)

Can I kindly ask that we're allowed to login without the OpenID nonsense? This system is so popular that stack-overflow is the only place that I use it.

If it is the policy of stack-overflow to prevent people to login, they've succeeded. I am a passive reader. For some reasons, I really don't like the idea of having one Id  for all sites. To me, this system is dead in the water. Unless used within organizations I will never use it. Of course, until the government decides to reign us all in. Will you give them a hand?

Until then, can we simply have a login form as in 1995? Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: You didn't give one single reason why you don't like OpenID and a "simple login form" would be better. There can be no discussion without arguments.

Comment: Some sites on stackexchange already do this, requiring only an email address and password.

Answer (score 1):

How can it be simpler than Open ID?

When I joined I just pressed the Google button and logged in as if I were logging into my email. No registration forms to fill out. No guessing usernames until I find one that is untaken.

I don't see the point of adding more ways of logging in. This will make it more complicated, not simpler as you claim.

Answer (score 1):

Annoyance: Every single time I use it, it sends me to the verisign page. I don't want the extra steps.

Security: To me, it is more secure to have a login per site. I know how to handle them.

Principle: A matter of principle. I don't care for verisign to have control over my logins. I really don't. I could care less how trustworthy verisign is. It is always subject to subpoena, to employee tampering, to warrant-less access. NO, I don't do anything illegal. I pay for software, I don't buy music. I simply don't want to give the keys to my house to someone else. Call me paranoid, it is my privilege.

I hope three reasons are enough.

Forth, you lose me as a customer regardless of your opinion concerning my reasons.

Regarding google login. No, I do not browse while logged in to google. Besides, I do not want google to know that I have a stack overflow account.

Comment: Even if you browse while logged out they still [might] receive a cooking identifying your account. You need to erase cookies before googling. Maybe even reconnect to the Internet to refresh your IP.

Comment: I periodically clean the browser. Imagine this. I go to www.kudzu.com and they ask me to login with facebook account. I go to mirriam webster dictionary, they ask me to comment with the facebook account. From that point of view, facebook is more successful than OpenId. Do you think they will ever win with me? I will give up on the keyboard before business and government follow my trace all over the map.

Comment: I read all the comments regarding openid. Even Jeff's blog entry. Conclusion? I have been given all the more reasons not to embrace OpenId. Consequence? OpenId will never make it to the masses. I'm a techie and resist it, how about my brother? He'd look long at you and change the subject. OpenId is a niche with business application. I know how important that is. I designed a SSO system in the past myself. Will SO change that? Jeff's got religion already. Besides it's too much to work and the SO audience will swallow it. I will continue to be a spectator. No harm done. Move on people.

Comment: The residual problem is that I feel someone is playing me. It's having me do things I don't want to do. This ain't death nor taxes so I'm being patronized. Bad for business if you asked me.

Comment: It's too late, [Google already knows](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=florin+site:stackoverflow.com/users/&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)

Comment: Is it not great that I have as many identities online as logins? Welcome to the cat and mouse world.

Comment: @florin you might try using http://myopenid.com rather than Verisign, as the experience is a bit smoother. Also, you don't need to log in to ask and answer questions.. so don't.

Comment: @Florin: two of your three reasons are actually in support of OpenID. If you don't like Verisign, you can easily switch to another OpenID provider - or even set up your own, where you have sole control over your own login information.

Comment: You can have a login per site with OpenID if you really want. Just create a new OpenID account for each site you use (maybe even use different OpenID provider for each site).

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to join it took me two weeks. First hours I couldn't understand what was being asked of me. I tried to copy this strange url:

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id
```

and follow it. Didn't work. Then replace the `id` with my login name. Again nothing. Then a week later I tried that again. It said something about no recipient at some endpoint builder, if I remember it correctly. I dropped it for the second time. A week later I tried that again and it suddenly worked.

Right now it seems to be easy but that was not the case in the beginning. I think the concept is too complicated for non-technical users.

While I see the advantages of the OpenID, I personally share your opinion and consider the idea to be quite dangerous. It only takes to hack your account and your little online world does not exist any more. Not to mention a generous source of information to track users' activities.

I personally do not understand Jeff's obsession with OpenID, neither do I think he's being nice to folks here forcing them into OpenID.

P.S. There is still an option missing to "unbind" your OpenID from the SO account. I strongly dislike this "lifetime" association.

Comment: "It only takes to hack your account and your little online world does not exist any more" this is *already* true of your email account, for which I could issue unlimited "password recovery requests" to every site you participate on, so I hope you have a really good password..